# Reference request for the smallest set( resp. abelian group) that a group ( resp. ring ) has a faithful action on

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-actions

For a proof of the Cayley's Theorem, it is obvious to see that a group ( resp. ring ) has a faithful action on itself by left-multiplication. I would like to extend the result for a bit and find the smallest set( resp. abelian group) that a group ( resp. ring ) has a faithful action on.

Comment: I believe this MSE question helps with the (finite) group case. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599089/the-smallest-symmetric-group-s-m-into-which-a-given-dihedral-group-d-2n-em

Comment: This question for groups is a difficult question and has lots of history.  Look for minimum faithful degree.

Comment: You can start with this paper D. L. Johnson. Minimal permutation representations of finite groups. Amer. J. Math.,
93:857–866, 1971.

Comment: And here is a more recent reference . A. Grechkoseeva. On minimal permutation representations of classical simple
groups. Sibirsk. Mat. Zh., 44(3):560–586, 2003.